# Passing a padded string with Ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to interface with a library. There is a method that needs a passed `char` buffer to be padded on both sides to write network header/footer in, **but** the pointer has to point *past* the pre-padding.

So far I've accomplished that by doing the following:

```
send_buffer = b'\0' * 18 + payload + b'\0' * 4
ptr = ctypes.cast (send_buffer, ctypes.c_void_p)
ptr.value += 18
lws.libwebsocket_write (wsi, ptr, len (payload), 0)
```

But this feels like a really evil way to do things.

Is this a *correct* way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cast` is returning the internal pointer of the Python string. Don't pass an immutable Python string to a function that expects a mutable buffer. Use `create_string_buffer` to create a mutable `char` array (read section [16.17.1.4. Fundamental data types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes#fundamental-data-types)). For the offset, use `byref` with the optional `offset` argument:

```
send_buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'\0' * 18 + payload + b'\0' * 4)
lws.libwebsocket_write(wsi, ctypes.byref(send_buf, 18), len(payload), 0)

send_buf.value # null terminated
send_buf.raw   # complete array
```